# magento new order template call from observer

Tags: php, magento-community

I need to call Magento new order template from one of my observers. Is there any way of doing that. i already defined the variables.

this is something that i tried. but didint work

```
$template = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('custom_email_template1');

       $template->send($emailaddress, null, array(
          'orderid' => $order->getIncrementId(),
          'items' => $items_string
       ));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the order id, you can use the `sendOrderUpdateEmail` method from the order model and not care about the template used.

```
$order = ...;//
$notifyCustomer = false;
$comment = 'If you need a comment added';
$order->sendOrderUpdateEmail();
```